# How can I access the container in a class that is not a service in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have a service defined in my config.yml

```
services:
  kinorm_pdo:
    class: Pate\KinormBundle\Dbal\Db
    arguments: [%kinorm.db_driver%,%kinorm.db_user%,%kinorm.db_pass%,%kinorm.db_name%,%kinorm.db_host%,%kinorm.db_charset%]
```

But I want to have access to this service in a class that is not a controller and I do not understand how to gain access to the container without injecting it.

Basicly I just want to do

```
$user = new User();
```

and have inside $user access to the container...

Thanks for any advice !

Comment: And why not creating a static function in the controller that returns the container ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you don't have direct access to the controller from inside an object unless you *do* inject it (which is most likely a bad idea, by the way)... but if you want your `kinorm_pdo` service available from your User class, just inject *that* (assuming that you're instantiating the class from a container-aware context):

```
$user = new User($this->container->get('kinorm_pdo'));
```

or even

```
$user = new User();
$user->setPdo($this->container->get('kinorm_pdo'));
```

Note that it sounds like you're trying to provide access to the database from inside an entity... [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) says this is probably not the cleanest way to accomplish whatever you're trying to do... if you provide a little more information on what you're trying to accomplish, we can probably help you with that, as well.

Comment: Well you understood completly, I'm trying to have access to my db from my models, I just don't get why I can't do queries in my object. I found so many case where creating a repository just seems weird...

Comment: I agree with Problematic. It is much better to put your methods into a repository and then pass in a User to the repository method.  The Doctrine repositories are already aware of which EntityManager to use and then your problem disappears.

Comment: Yes, this is a difference form how things have been done in the past, for better or worse. @markymark is totally correct that you should get into the habit of putting your methods into your repository and passing the user object to that method (e.g. `getSomeComplicatedInformationForUser($user)`). This is a bit more work and you may have to prepare more for your template in the controller, but it is a slightly cleaner pattern overall.