# How to get root dir in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to get the root dir in symfony2.

If I use:

```
$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
```

I get this error:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Test\Component\ClassLoader\DebugClassLoader::get()
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you calling this code? Within a controller?

Comment: Yes, into a controller, but before, I tried to call this function into another class.

Answer (score 20):

> Edit, seeing as this post has garnered so much attention and mine is at the top, the best way to get the root directory is to pass it in to your class as a constructor argument. You would use `services.yml` to do this, and in arguments:

```
serviceName:
  class: Name\Of\Your\Service
  arguments: %kernel.root_dir%
```

Then, the following code will have the root directory given to it when the framework instantiates it:

```
namespace Name\Of\Your;

class Service
{
    public function __construct($rootDir)
    {
        // $rootDir is the root directory passed in for you
    }
}
```

The rest of the answer below is the old, poor way of doing it without using Dependency Injection.

---

> I want to make everyone aware that this is the **Service Locator**, which is an **anti-pattern**. Any developer should be able to see what a class, or controller, requires to function from the **method signature only**. Injecting a whole "container" is very generic, hard to debug and **isn't** the best way of doing things. You should use a **Dependency Injection Container** that allows you to inject specifically what you want anywhere in your application. Be specific. Check out a *seriously awesome* recursively instantiating dependency injection container called [Auryn](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Auryn). Where your framework resolves your controller / action, place it there and use the container to  create the controller and run the method instead. Boom! Instant SOLID code.

You're correct, the service container is accessed using `$this->get('service')`.

However, in order to use `$this->get()`, you're going to need access to the `get()` method.

### Controller Access

You gain access to this, and many other handy methods, by making sure your controller extends the base controller class that Symfony uses.

Make sure you're referencing the correct Controller base class:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    /** The Kernel should now be accessible via the container **/
    $root = $this->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
}
```

### Service Access

If you want to access the container from a service, you're going to have to [define your controller as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/controller/service.html). You can find more information in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757916/symfony2-how-to-use-access-a-service-from-outside-of-a-controller), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8622382/how-do-i-get-services-dependencies-in-a-custom-class?lq=1) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379221/how-can-i-access-the-container-in-a-class-that-is-not-a-service-in-symfony-2?rq=1) about how to do this. Another [useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124444/how-can-i-access-a-service-outside-of-a-controller-with-symfony2). Either way, you now know what to look for. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7643391/symfony2-access-the-container-in-the-repository) may also be useful:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface; 

class MyClass
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function doWhatever()
    {
        /** Your container is now in $this->container **/
        $root = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir();
    }
}
```

In your config.yml, define your new type:

```
myclass:
  class: ...\MyClass
  arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

You can read more about the service container in [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html).

Comment: Thanks, but if I want to access to $this->get... not in a controller, else in another class, how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: @user2515999 I've updated the code. You need to use ContainerInterface.

Comment: Passing the container to a service is a bad practice !

Comment: @Shady Did you read the part at the top: **I want to make everyone aware that this is the Service Locator, which is an anti-pattern.**??

Answer (score 11):

The parameter `kernel.root_dir` points to the `app` directory. Normally to get to the root directory, I user `kernel.root_dir`/../

So in controller you can use `$this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir')."/../"`

In service definition you can use:

```
my_service:
    class: \Path\to\class
    arguments: [%kernel.root_dir%/../]
```

Comment: If you need only root application dir, use this way - inject only this parameter %kernel.root_dir% into your service.

Answer (score -5):

The best option is to declare tour class as a service in your services.yml file:

```
services:
    myclass:
        class: Your\Class\Namespace\MyClass
        arguments: ["@service_container"]
```

and adapt yhe constructor of you class:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface

class MyClass
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practise to inject the hole container !